# windowSoftInputMode with AppBarLayout | CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview, android-textinputedittext

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

This attribute is not working with `collapsingToolbar`. Can anyone please give me a fix for this?
I tried searching some other posts but didn't found any relevant solution for this.
Thank you :)

activity_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            ...
            android:layout_height="150dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ....
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/contentHome"
        layout="@layout/content_home" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputName"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ....
                 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ...
                 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
      </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the needed fixes:

- You only need to adjustResize: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
- Make sure to add the scrolling flags in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`
- If the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` didn't work with you try to use the material design one:
  `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fixes, but I don't how it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @PawanGorai Can you provide the sample.. the provided layouts looks like trimmed, also please tell us do you use them in the activity or in fragment and if so, who the fragment and activities both look like

Comment: I will soon create an issue for this in GitHub, I will drop the link here as well hope that's fine with you  :)

Comment: @PawanGorai probably you need to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the `NestedScrollView`